# Install4j "Text field with integer format" control issue

Tags: install4j

On one of my installer dialog, I am using "Text field with integer format" control. This control have property "Minimum number of digits". I have set it to 0.

Run time I entered some digits and try to delete all digits using Backspace or Delete key. But control kept one digit. Doesn't allowed me to delete last digit using Backspace or Delete key.

Even though I set "Minimum number of digits" to 0, why this control is not allowing me to clear all the digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the "Allow invalid input" property of the "Text field with integer format" form component, then you will be able to delete all digits.

Comment: "Allow invalid input" fixed the issue of clearing all digits issue. But now control allows me to enter alphabets (alphabets gets cleared on lost focus). And one more interesting issue as below.                                 1.Enter digit in integer control.  2. Move to next control.        3. Comeback to integer control and clear all digits.        4. Then again move to other control.  Here cleared value reappears in integer control.

Comment: Yes, that's how the underlying Swing component works, We have no way of changing that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more issue I observed described as below 1.Enter digit in integer control. 2. Move to next control. 3. Comeback to integer control and clear all digits. 4. Then again move to other control. Here cleared value reappears in integer control.

Comment: Again, this is the default behavior of the JFormattedTextField that we are using here and it cannot be changed.